# Multiple Linear Regression Machine Learning in Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to evaluate output based on certain input, using Multiple Linear Regression Machine Learning .I have trained the data and getting correct expected values while running below code:

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('TEST.xlsx')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 5].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 0])  # 1ST COLUMN 

labelencoder1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])  # 2ND COLUMN 

labelencoder2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder2.fit_transform(X[:, 2]) #  # 3RD COLUMN 

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = "all")
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)   # TILL HERE ITS WORKING AS EXPECTED
```

Now I am trying to use same model to evaluate another set of input data as below :

```
dataset1 = pd.read_excel('TEST1.xlsx')  # NEW SET OF INPUT RECORDS TO BE EVALUATE
X1 = dataset1.iloc[:, :-1].values
# Encoding categorical data
labelencoder3 = LabelEncoder()
X1[:, 0] = labelencoder3.fit_transform(X1[:, 0])

labelencoder4 = LabelEncoder()
X1[:, 1] = labelencoder4.fit_transform(X1[:, 1])

labelencoder5 = LabelEncoder()
X1[:, 2] = labelencoder5.fit_transform(X1[:, 2])

onehotencoder2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = "all")
X1 = onehotencoder2.fit_transform(X1).toarray()
X1 = X1[:, 1:]
output = regressor.predict(X1)
```

But while I am running this code getting below error:

> ValueError: shapes (6,13) and (390,) not aligned: 13 (dim 1) != 390 (dim 0)

It will be great if anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what are the outputs of `X.shape` and `X1.shape`

Comment: First of all, you must not create new `labelencoder` and `onehotencoder` for `X1`. Use the same `labelenocders` and `onehotencoder` that you used for `X_train`. Also, show the full eror message and the shape of `X_train` and `X1` after preprocessing steps.

Comment: If you are using latest scikit-learn, the  `OneHotEncoder` will handle the label-encoding itself. No need for separate `LabelEncoder` objects. And as for error, as @TirthPatel said, if the model is same then the preprocessing should also remain same. You should use same objects to just `transform()` (not fit_transform) the new data.

Comment: @ Rajitha: It looks like number  of columns is different in Feature data and Test data that's why it's giving ValueError. Can you help me how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the size of future between  X and X1  same??  
In case that X  contains five words, for example, the shape of X converted with OneHotEncoder is (n,5)  and regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) return the objection of y=b+a1x1+a2x2+…a5x5  
If X_1 contains 10 words, for example, the shape of X_1 converted with OneHotEnd is (n,10), that require the regressor object of y=b+a1x1+a2x2+….a10x10 so as to caluculate X_1 , which is generated by the training with data consisting of just 10 words. So, X_1 (n,10) would not be calculated  with  y=b+a1x1+a2x2+…a5x5  
 
What’s more, I think there is no need for toarray after onehotencoder.fit_transform()  
 I’m not sure my answer would help to solve your trouble, but  I hope.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable input. if I remove the toarray() , its throwing "dimension mismatch" while running the code:
output = regressor.predict(X1)

Comment: Glad to hear about your results! If you are somewhat satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it by clicking the green check next to the votes, so others immediately can see the results.